# Verilog getting 'x' as an output instead of '0' and '1'

Tags: verilog

I am trying to create a four element direct mapped cache with four bit memory address. Program is running completely fine no compilation error but suddenly in output, I am getting 'x' just for the first statement. After that I don't see it anywhere else. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the code

```
module cache_memory_direct_mapped(input clk,
                        input reset,
                        input [3:0]read_addr,
                        output reg hit,
                        output reg miss,
                        output reg [7:0]hit_count,
                        output reg [7:0]miss_count);
reg [1:0]c1[3:0];
initial 
begin
 hit_count =8'h00; 
 miss_count = 8'h00;
end 
            

always @(posedge clk, posedge reset)                        
 begin
   if(reset)
      begin
       c1[0] <= 2'hx;
       c1[1] <= 2'hx;
       c1[2] <= 2'hx;
       c1[3] <= 2'hx;
      end   
    else  
begin
  if(read_addr[3:2] == c1[0] || read_addr[3:2] == c1[1] || read_addr[3:2] == c1[2] || read_addr[3:2] ==     c1[3])
   begin
   hit <= 1;
   hit_count <= hit_count + 1;
   miss <= 0;
   end
 else
  begin
  hit <= 0;
  miss <= 1;
   miss_count <= miss_count + 1;
    if(read_addr[1:0] == 2'b0 )
        c1[0] <= read_addr[3:2];
    else if(read_addr[1:0] == 2'b1 )
      c1[1] <= read_addr[3:2];  
    else if(read_addr[1:0] == 2'b10 )
      c1[2] <= read_addr[3:2];        
    else if(read_addr[1:0] == 2'b11 )
      c1[3] <= read_addr[3:2];  
 end
 end
 end
endmodule

module Tb_direct_mapped;

// Inputs
reg clk;
reg reset;
reg [3:0] read_addr;

// Outputs
wire hit;
wire miss;
wire [7:0]hit_count;
wire [7:0]miss_count;

integer data_file ; // file handler
integer scan_file ; // file handler
reg [4:0]captured_data;

// Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
cache_memory_direct_mapped uut (
    .clk(clk), 
    .reset(reset), 
    .read_addr(read_addr), 
    .hit(hit), 
    .miss(miss),
    .hit_count(hit_count),
    .miss_count(miss_count)
);

initial begin
    // Initialize Inputs
    clk = 0;
    reset = 0;
    data_file = $fopen("data_file.txt", "r");
end

always
#10 clk= ~clk;


always @(posedge clk) begin
scan_file = $fscanf(data_file, "%h\n", captured_data);
if (!$feof(data_file)) begin
read_addr <= captured_data;
$display(hit);
//$display(hit_count);
end
else
$finish; 
end

  
endmodule
```

And here is the picture of the output
[image]

Comment: this is usually ok to have 'x' before reset is done. Except your reset is broken because you initialize it to `x`: `c1[0] <= 2'hx;`. The point of reset is to set it to a know value instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
    $display(hit);
```

to:

```
    $strobe(hit);
```

This outputs:

```
0
0
1
1
0
1
```

From the IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 21.2.2 *Strobed monitoring*:

> The system task $strobe provides the ability to display simulation
> data at a selected time. That time is the end of the current
> simulation time, when all the simulation events have occurred for that
> simulation time, just before simulation time is advanced.

The problem is that your signal values are changing at the time you call `$display` at posedge clk.

---

Here are some additional debugging tips:

1. Use a waveform debugger.
2. Display the simulation time as well as values: `$strobe($time, " ", hit);`

Answer (score 0):

I can see an issue inside the "cache_memory_direct_mapped".
Under the else inside always (copied and pasted below)

```
if(read_addr[1:0] == 2'b0 )
    c1[0] <= read_addr[3:2];
else if(read_addr[1:0] == 2'b1 )
  c1[1] <= read_addr[3:2];  
else if(read_addr[1:0] == 2'b10 )
  c1[2] <= read_addr[3:2];        
else if(read_addr[1:0] == 2'b11 )
  c1[3] <= read_addr[3:2];
```

1. under each if statement you only assign a value to one section of C1, the rest will not be updated and carries their initial 'X'values. Can you assign 0 to the rest in each is/else if?
2. What happens if none of the conditions are not satisfied, you may need to have else statement at the end as well.